# Python Print Statement Spacing

Tags: python

**My Question**
How do I remove the spaces in between 800 and the parenthesis surrounding the 800?

For example;

Instead of outputting ( 800 )

I would like it to be (800)

My code is below..

**Python Code**

```
phone_number = int(input())

last_four = phone_number % 10000

area_code = phone_number // 10000000

middle_three = (phone_number % 10000000) // 10000

print('(', area_code, ')', middle_three, '-', last_four)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use f-strings which are quite powerful and will help you later on as well

```
print(f'({area_code}){middle_three}-{last_four}')
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I attempted to use an f-string and happened to swap the placements of the parenthesis and curly brackets. I also did not realize that spacing was taken into consideration like that in f-strings. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happy to help!!

The print function considers everything separated by ',' as different objects, which was why you got the spaces between the paranthesis. You can look into f-strings more if you want as you can even do mathematical operations inside the {} (curly braces) of the f-string.